# How can I print only rows that have a precise column number greater than x ? Sheets Api with Python

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

So what I want to do is print only rows that have for example the price (or any other row "title" cell greater or equal to let's say 50.

I haven't been able to find the answer elsewhere and couldn't do it myself with the API documentation.
I'm using Google Sheets API v4 and my goal is based on a sheets that contain information on mobile subscription, allow user to select what they want for price, GB, etc.

Here is what my sheets look like:
[image: Here is what my sheets look like]

Also, here is [an unofficial documentation](https://readthedocs.org/projects/gspread/downloads/pdf/latest/) which I found great even though it didn't contain the answer I need, maybe someone here would succeed?

I tried running the following code but it didn't work:

```py
val_list = col5 

d = wks.findall(>50) if cell.value >50 :

print (val_list)
```

I hope you will be able to help me. I'm new to Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you had the right idea, but it looks like `findall` is for strings or regex, not an arbitrary boolean condition. Also, some of the syntax is a bit off, but that's to be expected when you are just starting out.

Here is how I would approach this with just what I could find in your attached document. I doubt this is the fastest or cleanest way to do this, but I think it's at least conceptually clear:

```
#list of all values in 4th/price column
prices=wks.col_values(4) 
#Remove nonnumeric characters from prices
prices=[p.replace('*','') for p in prices[1:]]

#Get indices of rows with price >=50
##i+2 to account for one indexing and removing header row
indices=[i+2 for i,p in enumerate(prices) if float(p)>=50]
#Print these rows
for i in indices:
    row=wks.row_values(i)
    print(row)
```

Going forward with this project, you may want to put these row values into a dataframe rather than just printing them so you can do further analysis on this subset of the data.

Comment: You rock it worked ! One other small question, could you elebarote  or link some info on doing a data frame? Bc G Sheets Api limit request to something like 1000 request per second and when I would finish my website , this could (evntually) become a problem.

Comment: @TechFan_Theo [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/) is the most common library for this in Python. I have linked to their documentation page, but there are also many questions on StackOverflow related to using pandas.

Comment: @TechFan_Theo consider upvoting/accepting if this solved your problem.